# How to use JavaScript template code within JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, templates, template-engine

Similarly to how we can use JS template engines (e.g. [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)) to dynamic insert values within HTML (e.g. `<div>{{value inserted by JavaScript}}</div>`), I would like to insert JavaScript code within JavaScript Code with the same `{{curly brackets}}` notation. For instance:

```
 var myFunction= {{My Function}};
 var bar = myFunction(foo);
```

Code defined within the `My Function` template:

```
function(foo) {
   return foo+'bar';
}
```

I tried to Google but I'm not getting anywhere as all the results are about JavaScript template engines (e.g. [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)).

**Any idea how I could achieve this in JavaScript within the browser?**

note 1: FYI the reason I want to achieve this is to create JavaScript functions I can unit-test in my browser, and reuse as-is (without have to replace `{{template}}` code) into JavaScript Functions used by [Google Tag Manager](https://www.google.com/tagmanager/) which supports `{{curly brackets}}` notation within it's JavaScript engine.

note 2: if it's too complicated, I will use a back-end language (e.g. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) in  PHP) to write my JavaScript code with `{{curly brackets}}` and return plain JavaScript to the browser so my unit tests work, and re-use the code as written in the backend.

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where you really need this,  because you can always pass functions like any other js object as argument to a function. I don't want to say that it might be useless, but are you really sure that you need that?

Comment: Having it would definitely be useful as it would allow me to develop + unit test my code and then literally just copy/paste into Google Tag Manager. Now I have to do some manual editing before porting my code to GTM which is error prone and defeats the unit testing which is to ensure my code is working as it should. My Google Tag Manager instance is being used to deploy analytics tags to websites that receive several millions of visitors each month, so making sure everything is working properly is really critical. Outside of this context, I don't see myself how this would be useful indeed :)

Comment: Handlebars - except the escaping - is not limited to HTML but can be used any language that won't have a syntax conflicting with Handlebars. As of that  you can use Handelbars because the `{{ }}` notation won't exists in js code. But because of the escaping you would need to use `{{{ }}}`  or define the data as SafeString.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval() to create dynamic JS code. Here's an example:

```
var getDynamicFunction = function(jsCode) { 
        return '(function() { return function() { ' + jsCode + ' }})()'
   },
   codeToInsert = 'alert("I am created dynamically");';

myFunction = eval(getDynamicFunction(codeToInsert));
myFunction();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pLk3nsv3/1/

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I was aware of `eval`, but I still don't see how I will be able to use `{{template}}` notation within my JavaScript code and have it replace by other JavaScript using this technique.